# How to use Jackson HyperSchema to generate schema link references

Tags: json, rest, jackson, jsonschema, hateoas

I'm using Jackson jsonSchema(https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-jsonSchema), to automate schema creation for my data model.

According to samples provided in http://json-schema.org/ and in jsonSchema, the format used by json shema includes links

```
{
  "name":"Product",
  "properties":{
    "id":{
      "type":"number",
      "description":"Product identifier",
      "required":true
    },
    "name":{
      "description":"Name of the product",
      "type":"string",
      "required":true
    },
    "price":{
      "required":true,
      "type": "number",
      "minimum":0,
      "required":true
    },
    "tags":{
      "type":"array",
      "items":{
        "type":"string"
      }
    }
  },
  "links":[
    {
      "rel":"full",
      "href":"{id}"
    },
    {
      "rel":"comments",
      "href":"comments/?id={id}"
    }
  ]
}
```

But I can't find a way to add it to the generated, schema, although there is a HyperSchema object, which seems to be what I need, but I can't find how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made an issue in json-schema project, and a pull request to support HyperSchema, based on annotations, in a form

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-jsonSchema/issues/35

```
public class Pet {
    public String genus;
}

@JsonHyperSchema(pathStart = "/persons/", links = {
    @Link(href = "{name}", rel = "self"),
    @Link(href = "{name}/pet", rel = "pet", targetSchema = Pet.class)
})
public class Person {
    public String name;
    public String hat;
}
```

Changes are in https://github.com/clemble/jackson-module-jsonSchema